# docker linked container all ports closed

Tags: linker, docker, containers, derby

i try to connect from one docker container to another.

- Container A has a Derby DB installed and started, listening on port 3301
- Container B should connect to Container A

the docker files look like:
Container A

```
FROM java:8

# Install Derby
COPY db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin.tar.gz db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin.tar.gz

RUN mkdir /opt/Apache 
RUN cp db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin.tar.gz /opt/Apache 
RUN tar xzvf /opt/Apache/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin.tar.gz

EXPOSE 3301
CMD ["/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/bin/startNetworkServer", "-p 3301"]
```

Container B

```
FROM java:8 

# Install nmap
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nmap
COPY db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin.tar.gz db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin.tar.gz

RUN mkdir /opt/Apache 
RUN cp db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin.tar.gz /opt/Apache 
RUN tar xzvf /opt/Apache/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin.tar.gz
EXPOSE 9080
```

I start both container and give them names
Container A

```
docker run -it --name derby <image>
```

Container B

```
docker run -it --link derby:derby <image> /bin/bash
```

Then i attach container B and

```
ping derby or ping 172.17.0.2
```

which is succesfull. But when i try to connect to the derby database via cli tool and giving a jdbc url like

```
connect 'jdbc:derby://172.17.0.2:3301/testdb;create=true';
```

I get an connection refused error.

Using nmap to scan the ports of container A results in "All ports are closed"
which is confusing because Docker References states:

> So what does linking the containers actually do? You’ve learned that a
>   link allows a source container to provide information about itself to
>   a recipient container. In our example, the recipient, web, can access
>   information about the source db. To do this, **Docker creates a secure
>   tunnel between the containers that doesn’t need to expose any ports
>   externally on the container**; you’ll note when we started the db
>   container we did not use either the -P or -p flags. That’s a big
>   benefit of linking: we don’t need to expose the source container, here
>   the PostgreSQL database, to the network.

Has anybody maybe a hint or solution for me?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The port is not open as you have not told docker to open it.

`EXPOSE` in the Dockerfile instructs docker that the container listens on the specified port, but it does NOT open that port or expose it to the host.

`--link` doesn't open ports either, that is the benefit of link, you can securely connect 2 containers without having to expose any ports to the host.

So, to connect to the derby BD with your command line tool you have 2 options.

1) Open the port - (possible security implications?)

When you run the container, you specificy the port to open.

```
docker run -it --name derby -p 3301:3301 <image>
```

The above will map the 3301 port on the container to the 3301 port on the host.

Then you can use the host IP and port 3301 to connect to that container.

2) Connect to the container directly

You can effectively ssh in to the container and run the command on the container itself...

```
$ sudo docker exec -it derby bash
```

And then you have a bash session on the derby container directly, and can run commands on it.

**UPDATE**

To connect from one container to another over the link you can use the ENV vars that docker exposes on the container about the link. http://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#environment-variables

So, on container B you will have ENV vars containing the link name `DERBY`.

So, `DERBY_PORT` will be a IP and PORT to connect to the derby container.

However, if the "derby" container is restarted, the IP in the ENV var will be out of date.  So it is better to connect to it by its link name.

Docker also sets up host names about the links, so you can connect to the derby container with

```
http://derby:3301
```

from within container B

So you could try..

```
connect 'jdbc:derby://derby:3301/testdb;create=true';
```

Comment: Ok, i tried option 1 but the result is the same. inside container B i cannot connect to container A. nmap output: Nmap scan report for derby (172.17.0.2)
Host is up (0.000077s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
3301/tcp closed unknown
MAC Address: 02:42:AC:11:00:02 (Unknown)
Option 2 is not really clear to me, wouldn't i execute docker from the host?

Comment: AH!  sorry, I miss understood, I didn't realise you were running the command from within another container.  When docker creates a link, it also exposes a bunch of ENV vars on the container about the link.  Using those you can target the linked machine... http://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/

Comment: So, in the container you are trying to run the command from, there will be an ENV var called `DERBY_PORT` and this will contain a host IP and PORT of the Derby link

Comment: one word of warning though, if the DERBY host is restarted, the link IP in the other container is NOT updated.  If this will be an issue, you can connect to it via its `name`.   Ill update the answer......

Comment: Yes i know about the variables, but it is not working set outup is the following: DERBY_ENV_CA_CERTIFICATES_JAVA_VERSION=20140324
DERBY_ENV_JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION=8u66-b17-1~bpo8+1
DERBY_ENV_JAVA_VERSION=8u66
DERBY_ENV_LANG=C.UTF-8
DERBY_NAME=/claas_overview/derby
DERBY_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.2:3301
DERBY_PORT_3301_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.2:3301
DERBY_PORT_3301_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.2
DERBY_PORT_3301_TCP_PORT=3301
DERBY_PORT_3301_TCP_PROTO=tcp
but i still can't connect to the derby container

Comment: out if interest did yo try `connect 'jdbc:derby://derby:3301/testdb;create=true';`

Comment: jup, didn't work either, but it seems that the derby cli tool can't handle env vars.

Comment: `derby` should be a valid host name on container B, can you ping it from within the container?

Answer (score 1):

Allright i got it solved. For all others who might be interessted, you need to start Derby with command

```
startNetworkServer -h 0.0.0.0
```

that way you tell Derby to accept **all** connections from outside, restrict it if you need but the parameter has to be present otherwise connections are refused.

Regards